# How can create a class with changeable name by use php?

Tags: php

I need to create class with changeable name.

I tried to do that by below code, but it is not work

```
<?php
$Class_Name = "test";

class $Class_Name {

    //
    //
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need this?

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: I work with framework, So I need that

Comment: And how are you thinking of changing it?

Comment: You mean like. $classname = 'test'; $obj = new $test(); ? Why not just use stdClass and add methods on the fly? The classname itself shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I found some other questions by searching for `[php] dynamic class name`, but none have a solution for the general case. There are some kludges for more limited requirements, take a look at the search results.

Comment: This would not work at any point as PHP would not be able to know what file/class to reference when you say $var = new Whatever();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating dynamic class name which is not available in php, you can create class alias  by the function class_alias, below an example

```
class foo{
    function getData(){
        echo "Example";
    }
}

class_alias("foo","bar");


$bar = new bar;

$bar->getData();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php